# Gitlab CI > IF Condition does not match in runner

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gitlab-ci, glob

I have a Shell Script, which I execute in the before_script section in the gitlab-ci.yaml, which looks like this:

```
if [[ "${branch}" == "@(feature)*" ]] || [[ "${branch}" == "@(development)*" ]]
then
    echo 'dev'
else 
    echo 'qa'
fi
```

My Branch on which I test is named 'feature/qa-environment'

When I test locally the terminal echoes out 'dev' as it should do.
If this gets executed in the Gitlab Job however I get the messages

```
[[ feature/qa-environment == @(feature)* ]]
./Scripts/get_context.sh: 9: ./Scripts/get_context.sh: [[: not found
[[ feature/qa-environment == @(development)* ]]
./Scripts/get_context.sh: 9: ./Scripts/get_context.sh: [[: not found
```

and it echoes out 'qa' cause it doesn't match the condition.

Can anyone tell me if something is wrong with my code?

Comment: `[[: not found` `[[` is a  bash feature. What is your shebang?

Comment: Is it possible to share your `.gitlab-ci.yml`? It's make easier to help.

Comment: @KamilCuk Good Point. Shebang was #!/bin/sh, changing to #!/bin/bash and removing the quotes on the right side of the equation solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
[ "${branch}" == "@(feature)*"  -o "${branch}" == "@(development)*" ] && echo "dev" || echo "qa"
```

I am on Mac so I am not sure if "sh" actually leads me to an old shell. But I think it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Shebang was #!/bin/sh, changing to #!/bin/bash and removing the quotes on the right side of the equation solved it